# Ссылка в iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Не могу открыть ссылку в iframe.

```
<button class="button" id="login">
    <a href="/lesson_08/login.html" target="myFrame"> Login </a>
</button>
```

Эта кнопка находится в iframe с именем "myFrame", и в нем мне надо открыть другой файл, но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Эта кнопка не может находиться в iframe с именем "myFrame". Она должна находиться в странице, в которой также есть iframe с именем "myFrame".

Comment: @Igor как сложно >< эти iframe-ы такие запутанные

Comment: Держитесь, дальше будет хуже :).

Comment: @IgorIgor, просто ей звоните за такую просьбу, но можно ли вас попросить точнее объяснить решение? В чате или здесь - как вам удобнее. Была бы очень  благодарна)

Comment: "просто ей звоните" - номер телефона?

Comment: @Igor, это должно было быть "простите-извините", писала через телефон, вот и поправил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, у меня на сайте рядом лежат два html файла, "test.html":

```html
<iframe name="testframe"></iframe>
<br/>
<a href="test1.html" target="testframe">Show in Frame</a>
```

и "test1.html":

```html
<b>Test - frame content.</b>
```

Как Вы видите, в первой странице находится ссылка на "test1.html" с атрибутом `target="testframe"`. При щелчке по этой ссылке, страница "test1.html" загрузится в `iframe`, а страница со ссылкой останется без изменений.

Comment: О, спасибо. Кажется, разобралась. Выходит, просто надо эту кнопку, которая ведет на страницу входа, margin-ами поместить на фрейм :3 ещё раз спасибо, у меня это забрало не мало времени

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов!